# How do you: Compile code on linux with gcc and run on windows?

Tags: compiling

So I am working on a big project in c++. I am on linux using eclipse for c++. Will this work on windows. I am compiling it with the "Linux GCC" because the "Cross GCC" comes up with me asking to add compiler paths and stuff which I dont understand and no answer is to on the internet. So how do i compile my c++ code once and get it to work on linux and windows?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a cross-compiler is used to build for the same operating system but a different *architecture* — like building for ARM on an Intel system. However, there is thing called [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) which uses basically the same concepts and includes a minimal GNU runtime so you can easily make programs that compile on a GNU/Linux system and run on Windows.

There's a question and answer over on Stack Overflow which covers setting this up in Eclipse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998425/use-mingw-in-eclipse-on-linux

Note, though, that you'll need to compile your code *twice* — C++ just isn't designed for "write once, run anywhere". And, you may need to provide Windows-specific sections where the operating system abstractions don't mix.

Comment: +1, although nowadays [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/) is probably the better bet.